# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 39-44: ordinal not in range(128

Tags: python, api

Доброго времени суток. Я понимаю, что тем с таким названием пруд пруди, но ответы в моей ситуации мне не помогли.

Работаю с Python 3. Имеется `.py` файл, который берет с `txt` файла строку, подставляет её в ссылку с api, получает `json` объект и запихивает данные в БД. (код ниже)

Ошибка `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 39-44: ordinal not in range(128)` возникает на моменте открытия `json` строки `urlopen`

В постах, в 90% можно увидеть ответ `.encode('utf-8')`, это конечно хорошо, но строку вида `\xef\xbb\xbf\xd0\xaf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\x9a` API не воспримет, ему подавай нормальные строки.

```
..................
f = open('C:/rus_for_info.txt', "r", encoding='UTF8')
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    name = line
    name = name.replace('\'', '%27')
    name = name.replace(' ', '%20')

    print("\Название" + name)

    url = "http://site.com/?method=name.getinfo&name="+name+"&api_key=dfgdgfdgf34t23fgwf2t4gfdg3g2xvbfgmnk&format=json"
    with urlopen(url) as response:
        data = json.load(response)
        Group = data['group']['name']
        Image = data['group']['image'][1]['src']
.................
```

П.с. В строке находится Русский и Украинский текст, с Англоязычным текстом проблем - нет

Буду рад любой помощи или ответу.
Спасибо!

Comment: Так вы параллельно используйте и `decode('кодировка')`

Comment: @KitScribe не получается, все равно ругается на ту же ошибку

Comment: @ВладимирВ. какая кодировка в файле? Можете попробовать использовать `chardet` для определения кодировки, затем decode и encode в utf-8

Comment: ну и в догонку - попробуйте строить url params с помощью готовой библиотеки `urllib.quote` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python